# Difficulty when working in QGIS with ArcGIS Map Server Layer

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server

I need to perform a point in polygon analysis in QGIS on parcel data from an Ohio Department Resources MapServer: 
https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis_site2/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase_v2/MapServer

The parcel layer will load as a MapServer layer, but fails when trying to load it as a Feature Server layer. The other layers from the server will load as a FeatureServer layer. This is the error I get when trying to load it as a feature server:

```
Layer is not valid : The layer crs='EPSG:3857' filter='' url='https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis_site2/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase_v2/MapServer/4' table="" sql= is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason: AFSProvider getObjectIds failed: Network error - Operation canceled
```

Loaded as MapServer layer, I can use the identify features tool to view the attributes of each parcel individually. However, whenever I attempt to perform any functions with the raster, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 4: ` crs='EPSG:3857' format='PNG32' layer='4' url='https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis_site2/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase_v2/MapServer' table="" sql=' 
does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

Ideally, I'd like to convert the raster to vector then use it in a point in polygon analysis. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for posting Mapperz. What you linked to is the land subdivision layer, which I can get to load just fine. What I need to work with is the Statewide Parcels layer, which I cannot get to load.

Answer (score 1):

Works in QGIS 3.8+

You can get the **vector data** with the feature service.

Add a ArcGIS Feature Service with the following url

> `https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis_site2/rest/services`

[image]

and export to your choice of vector format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tested with 3.8.3, I get the identical results that you report.  A couple of thoughts:

According to https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis_site2/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase_v2/MapServer/4 it *should* be available as a feature service (for example, the url states Geometry Type: esriGeometryPolygon).  [It might be worthwhile for you to contact them](http://geospatial.ohiodnr.gov/contacts-about-us/contacts-and-staff) and see if this error is the result of a boo-boo at their end, or a conscious decision that they made (say to minimize demand on their server due to the layer's large size).

You mention an interest in converting the *Map Service* raster to vector.  If you do, the resulting vector will not have any associated attribute fields (parcel #, address, owner name, etc).  It will be nothing more than a vector picture of the *Map Service* layer; you won't even have the luxury of getting a parcel's info by clicking on it with the Identify Features button.  But lack of attribute data may not be important to you...

You might also consider contacting the [Ohio DNR GIS Program](http://geospatial.ohiodnr.gov/contacts-about-us/contacts-and-staff) to see if you could acquire the parcel layer (in vector format, with the associated attribute fields) directly, for example, via an ftp site.